# Logic for creating custom side bar

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

As a beginner in Angular, I want to create a custom directive such that when applied on some div, it would act as a collapsible / expandable left menu bar, something like:

[here](https://pixinvent.com/bootstrap-admin-template/robust/html/ltr/vertical-menu-template/dashboard-ecommerce.html) or [here](https://bootsnipp.com/search?q=left%20admin%20menu)

If it's not Angular, I would have created it using li and ui with some jQuery. As we can't apply that in Angular, can I have some experts ideas on how to create this menu by myself.

I don't want to use material's bar and other ready-made tools.

Thanks

Comment: create component inserted of directive

Comment: is there any sort of example or reference on how to do it? You mean to say I should create a component but component is itself a directive. isn't it?